# StrongTypingException was unhandled by Usercode" While Databinding to control

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a datarow `drTask` and have a Column `Team` with null value. I am data binding the null value to my control. The below piece of code is working fine on .NET 2.0.

```
if (!drTask.IsTEAMNull())
{
    this.lookUpEditMyTeams.DataBindings.Add("Text", drTask, "TEAM");
}
else
{
    this.lookUpEditMyTeams.DataBindings.Add("Text", drTask, "TEAM", true);
}

//In else part am databinding null value
```

The same peace of code in .NET 4.0 throwing exception like

> "StrongTypingException was unhandled by Usercode" The value for column
>   'DESCRIPTION' in table 'Table' is DBNull.

Why my code is working in .NET 2.0 and not in .NET 4.0?

Comment: Did the datatypes or anything changed from previos version ?

Comment: Nothing is changed just migrated framework from 2.0 to 4.0